# What do folks understand by the tag "backyard-garden"?

Tags: discussion, tags

What do you understand by the tag [backyard-garden](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backyard-garden)? It means nothing to me and I can't see what the 3/4 questions under that tag have in common.

But maybe it's a term in general use somewhere in the world, and means something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the tag is redundant with most people's use of [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) and should be edited out. Feel free to correct me if someone sees a need for this tag, but for now I would edit it out with prejudice, possibly going as far as to ask for it to be blacklisted it if it becomes a problem...

Comment: i've edited it out of questions

Answer (score 2):

Well, your "front garden" faces the street, so it is much more likely to be ornamentals and managed for aesthetics.

Your "back garden" or "backyard garden" is hidden from street view. That's where you grow your potatoes, cabbage, etc.

I've heard that some HOAs/zoning ban vegetable gardens in the front garden. In those communities, corn or pumpkins in the front yard are illegal...

I *think* that's the rationale behind having [backyard-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backyard-gardening), but I agree that it's probably a useless tag. As wax eagle said, it's either redundant to [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) (which is redundant to being on this site), or it's redundant to [vegetable-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetable-gardening).

+1 on getting rid of it.

Comment: i get what you're saying about it being a term for your hidden, non-showy parts of your garden but even that didn't really seem to apply to the handful of questions which had the tag. one question tagged [tag:backyard-gardening] was about roof top gardens!

Comment: @TeaDrinker - sounds like it needs to go then. I don't agree with it being redundant to vegetable gardening, but otherwise yes it is just gardening to me!